# how to get all the tags from headlines in a org-mode file

Tags: emacs, tags, org-mode

When I incrementally write up a org-mode file, I add tags to the current headline on the spur (instead of predefine it at the beginning of the file with `+TAGS:`). However, without predefining the tags in the file, I can not get a list of tags already existing in the other headlines for autocompletion or for simply viewing. This causes me to set semantically similar but different words as tags. For example, I repeatedly used `book` and `reading` for similar headlines. I want to avoid this. Is there anyway to overcome this? One simple approach, for example, is to get and view all the tags in the file.

Answer (score 0):

To get a view of all the tags in a file you can press `TAB` when entering a tag.

`C-c C-c TAB` (`org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c`) or `C-c C-q TAB` (`org-set-tags-command`) will present you a buffer with the used tags for you to autocomplete.

You can also setup *fast tag selection* as per [the docs](https://orgmode.org/manual/Setting-Tags.html)